# Can i increase my maximum Mana capacity later?

Tags: atelier-iris-1

I started playing *Atelier Iris: Eternal Mana* on the weekend, after 1 hour of playing i had already collected 99 Water/Wood Mana.

i am wondering if i can boost this limit at some point in the game or if 99 is the maximum that i'll ever have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, 99 is the limit of what you'll be able to carry.  You don't need to worry about it too much, either.  It's pretty simple to get the elements, and there's no limit to how often you can gather.

Incidentally, they change the alchemy system after this game, due to it being so simplistic in this one.  This is the only one where you "hold" elemental mana.